# About the "force close/wait" notification

Tags: android, dialog, wait

I have an app with a list view that downloads images on the fly. They are very small images and they are being stored after downloading. However, if the user has a very slow connection (and I mean very slow), it lags and the user is prompted with a "Force Close or Wait?" dialog.

I am wondering if I can catch this before the user get's notified, which would enable me to kill my thread, throw my own custom dialog up and handle it how I want.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting an `ANR (application not responding)` dialog because you are blocking the UI thread. THIS IS BAD! Do all your long running tasks (*like network or file IO*) on a separate thread say `AsyncTask`.

You can use [Strict Mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) to detect where you are misusing the UI thread.

Suggest you to look for [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html) and [Multi-Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

Comment: StrictMode is nice, but only became available at API level 9 (Android 2.3).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are doing your downloads on the UI thread. This is contrary to recommended practice and, as of Honeycomb, will throw an exception. See the article [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for ways to move your network activity off the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you probably dont want to be downloading images on the UIThread. You probably should move the loading of the images onto a background thread so that you dont get the ANR in the first place.

You could look at using AsyncTask or similar to do the work so you dont have to write the thread sync code yourself.